# Finding the rank of subgroups of free groups?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

How do you find the rank of a subgroup(of finite index) of a free group?

I was thinking of looking at the fundamental group of a graph.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the free group $\,F\,$ has rank $\,n\,$ and the index of the subgroup $\,K\leq F\,$  is $\,k\,$, the group $\,K\,$ is free on $\,k(n-1)+1\,$ generators.

You can find this formula in several books, for example in the classic Magnus-Karrass-Solitar (theorem 2.10), or in Lyndon-Schupp (Proposition 3.9)

Comment: what about a proof by looking at covering spaces?

Comment: Can be that, can be with directly by Tietze transformations or even by actions of (free) groups on trees. Nevertheless, this all is old history for me and I don't think I'll get into this here.

Comment: I'm basically interested to know how to show this by use of covering spaces.??

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Euler characteristic. For a free group of rank n, this is easily seen to $n-1$. For a subgroup of index $k$ we get Euler characteristic $k(n-1)$. Hence the rank $M$ satisfies  $M-1=k(n-1)$ or $M=kn-k+1$.

Comment: do you mean $1-n$?

Answer (score 2):

Take a wedge of $n$ spheres. This has fundamental group the free group on $n$ generators $F_n$. Let $G$ be a subgroup of $F_n$ of index $k$. Associated to $G$ is a $k$-fold connected covering space $P$ of the wedge of spheres. This covering space is again a 1-dimensional CW complex (or a graph, if you prefer) with $k$ vertices and $nk$ edges. A maximal tree in this graph has $k-1$ edges. Contracting this maximal tree, we obtain a wedge of $nk-(k-1)$ spheres. Hence the fundamental group of $P$ is free on $nk-k+1$ generators. But by definition of the cover associated to $G$, this fundamental group is isomorphic to $G$ and we are home.