# Prove any subgroup $A$ of $n$-elements-generated group $G$ has can be generated by $2n[G:A]$ elements

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ can be generated by n elements,
$A$ is a subgroup of $G$ and index $(G:A)$ is finite,

I was required to prove: $A$ can be generated by $2n(G:A)$ elements.

There is an answer that A generally cannot be generated by only n elements when G is non-abelian, but the upper bound here is much higher.([If a group $G$ is generated by $n$ elements, can every subgroup of $G$ by generated by $\leq n$ elements?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1182877/873413))

Thank you!

Comment: In fact  $(n-1)|G:A|+1$ elements are enough to generate $A$. This follows from the result for free groups - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239987) for example.

Comment: Why the close votes? There are many questions around that are for more worthy of close votes than this one.

Comment: The group $G$ is not necessarily free. It is finitely generated but can have any relation between the generators, thus $[G:A]$ may be smaller than $[F(S):A]$ when S generates G.

Comment: But the point is that the result for $G$ follows immediately from the result for the free group $F$ on $n$ generators, because $G$ is a quotient group of $F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

It seems [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/13100/655547) does what you want. In particular, the factor of $2n$ comes from ensuring the generating set $Y$ of $G$ symmetric, and the factor of $(G:A)$ comes from taking a transversal $S$ of $G/A$.

Following that answer, if we write $[g]$ to mean the chosen representative of $Ag$ in $S$, induction on word length shows $\{ sy [sy]^{-1} ~|~ s \in S, y \in Y \}$ (which has size $2n[G:A]$) generates $A$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Followed your link and found an elegant proof (albeit took me some time to understand it). Thank you!

Comment: But the question does not ask for a symmetric generating set, so $n|G:A|$ generators suffice (which can be improved to $(n-1)|G:A|+1$).

Comment: I don't think it's true, if Y isn't symmetric (after careful analyzing) we may well find $\{ sy^{-1} [sy^{-1}]^{-1} ~|~ s \in S, y \in Y \}$ among the generating elements of A. I hope others to clarify though.

Comment: But those generators are redundant, because $sy^{-1}[sy^{-1}]^{-1} = ([sy^{-1}]ys^{-1})^{-1} = ([sy^{-1}]y[sy^{-1}y]^{-1})^{-1}$ (hope I've got that right!)